# Python program runs but finishes with exit code 0

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ext9G7xspg) on YouTube.

I've followed along and written the code, yet when I run it, the program finishes instantly without inputting into the console.

Here's my code:

```py
import random

def play():
    user = input("'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors")
    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

    if user == computer:
        return 'Its a tie!'

    # r > s, s > p, p > r
    if is_win(user, computer):
        return 'You won!'

    return "You lost!"

def is_win(player, opponent):
    # return true is player wins
    # r > s, s > p, p > r
    if (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponent == 'p') \
        or (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r'):
        return True
```

And this is the console output:

```
"C:\Users\BenAr\PycharmProjects\Rock Paper Scissors\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/BenAr/PycharmProjects/Rock Paper Scissors/Rock_Paper_Scissors.py"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be running the main `play()` function. Do note it says "exit code 0" meaning program finished, not "line 0".

Try adding this at the bottom of the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    play()
```

It will run the `play()` function when the module is executed.

Keep in mind you shouldn't `return 'Its a tie!'` without printing it or doing something else with the return value.